# Firebase storage is locked

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

my Firebase storage is locked.
"Unable to upload files because the project limit has been exceeded"

here where the limit has been exceeded:

[image]

does it unlock itself or do I have to do something?

Comment: You can only download upto 1GB a day in the Spark (Free) Plan. You will have to upgrade your project to the Blaze plan to download more.

Comment: I always recommend searching for any errors you get. In combination with the correct tags, you can often find previous questions about the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-storage%5D+project+limit+has+been+exceeded